# Regarding address operator C/C++

Tags: c++

What does address operator mean.

say in the method below.

what should be passed in the method as parameter value of integer or the address of an integer variable.

```
void func1(int&)// method declaration

void func1(int& inNumber)//method definition
{ 
//some code
}
```

Comment: Note that although people often conflate them, C and C++ are separate languages (there is no "C/C++"). This question hits one of the areas where they differ: there are no reference types in C, so this is a pure C++ question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the ampersand for when used after class name like ostream& operator <<(...)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1572016/90527)

Answer (score 11):

That’s not the address operator – it’s the reference type character. This means that for any type `T`, `T&` is a *reference to `T`*. It’s an unlucky coincidence that this happens to be the same character as the address operator.

You can pass normal objects to this method. No need to take any further action. Read up on references in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 3):

There is no address-of operator in your code - the ampersand is being used to declare a reference. Which C++ text book are you using that does not cover this?

Comment: @Neil I am not a C/C++ developer for time being. Just doing in Cocoa. SO forgot all those things...

Comment: @iSight Again, C does not have references.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the function takes a reference to an int which is denoted by the `int &inNumber`.

The function is called as if you were calling it with the value:

```
int x = 2;
func1(x);
```

From the perspective of the caller, this looks exactly the same as a pass by value function, though in the case of the reference the function may indeed change the value of x.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an address operator. In a declaration, the `&` means it's a *reference*.

You can think of references as pointers that you don't have to dereference.* You can just say `inNumber = 5;` (instead of `*inNumber = 5;`) and the effect will be visible outside the function.

* Note: References are *not* just "pointers that you don't have to dereference". It just helps to think of them in that way, sometimes.

Comment: ok then, in my case when i have to call that method how should i pass the parameter to it when called. please make it explicitly w.r.t. my sample example.

Comment: Just as if it were a normal value. `int x; func1(x);`

Answer (score 0):

its called as reference in c++ 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)